# does more stuff come in then go out?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> does more stuff come in then go out?
>   out is a drip, more than a spout
>   in was so loud, but did not shout
>   as far as sizes go they are really quite big
>   but the biggest is a synonym for baggage
>   yet if you please,
>   for who's a gnat homies,
>   tell me who has these?
>   those who are shavings near molasses
>   may have one without glasses
>   so close to a synonym for soldier is the small one
>   a rhyme with drinks born of wrath is one
>   why is it so corny with a face so pail?
>   oh! another has one to go below gales
>   *and often in them too!*

*Disclaimer: this has naught to do with typists.*

Answer (score 5):

Is it

> Nose

does more stuff come in then go out?

> You inhale smells, air, and other particles and blow out the same

out is a drip, more than a spout

> Your nose can drip when you have a cold, blow your nose to get more

in was so loud, but did not shout

> When you sneeze or blow your nose or snore breathing

as far as sizes go they are really quite big

> Some people/animals have really big noses

but the biggest is a synonym for baggage

> Biggest nose would be an elephant trunk, a synonym for baggage

yet if you please,
for who's a gnat homies,

> A mosquito has a proboscis @B540Glenn

tell me who has these?

> All humans/animals?

those who are shavings near molasses

> You slowly shave your mustache to avoid your nose

may have one without glasses

> A nose can hold up glasses

so close to a synonym for soldier is the small one

> A snout is close to a scout

a rhyme with drinks born of wrath is one,

> a muzzle is a nose, might guzzle down drinks if you're angry

why is it so corny with a face so pail?

> Unsure of this one

oh! another has one to go below gales

> The nose of a plane, fly through storms

and often in them too!

> People can be nosy, in your business.

Comment: A gnat's homies might be a mosquito, which has a long proboscis.

Comment: "A face so pail?"  Should that be "pale?"

Comment: @B540Glenn good idea!  and Rob, I left it as the author did. Unsure of what he meant.

Comment: I have to give you credit because the answer is in there.  There is a little more wordplay to the clues that you didn't get which should narrow down the results a bit.  Some of the clues are one line and some are combined.

Comment: @jmb.mage Wrong answer, or right answer with wrong interpretation of clues?

Comment: 'drinks born of wrath' is probably wine - a product of grapes, and 'the grapes of wrath' is a famous novel